# Why is magento so slow on Windows 10?

Tags: magento

When i install magento 2 on my Windows 10 WAMP/XAMPP, it runs so slow.

Is this some general problem of Magento with Windows? My laptop has 8GB RAM, 2x2.7 GHZ, 500GB HDD, 512MB VRAM.

Also same is on PC's at my office who has 8GB RAM and SSD, also on my friend's laptop with SSD and 8GB RAM...

What cause this? I tested with PHP7, MariaDB, everything i find on web (memory limits etc..), but it is always slow...

Is there any solution of this? If i install magento on Linux virtual machine it will be better?

Thanks.

Comment: Magento is slow. That's it's fundamental nature. There's a reason https://www.google.com/search?q=speeding+up+magento has a bunch of results.

Answer (score 1):

How hard it can be to read the [official documentation](https://magento.com/resources/system-requirements)?

> **System Requirements for Magento Enterprise Edition and Community
>   Edition (Current Shipping Versions)**
>
> Magento requires a LAMP or LNMP
>   stack
>
> **Operating System**
>
> Linux x86-64

Magento also has own Stack Exchange site, where this is [answered](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/14848):

> In the 5+ years I have been using magento, I had never come across
>   anyone who did host it on a windows platform for a live site.

Also, you are trying to run server software.... on a laptop... on a friend's laptop... on Windows 10, which is not a server edition of Windows. So much off-topic.